# phpMailer não está pegando os valores do meu banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, sql-select

Estou tentando recuperar e-mail e senha, onde:

```
$o_email = $_GET['email'];
$celular = $_GET['celular'];
```

Recebe via URL o e-mail ou o celular do usuário. Mas não estou conseguindo pegar estes dados recuperados para jogar no phpMailer.

O que posso estar fazendo errado?

```
<?php


header('Content-type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


include 'database.php';
include '../phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$o_email = $_GET['email'];
$celular = $_GET['celular'];


                $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nome, email, senha, celular FROM usuario_app WHERE email = '$o_email' OR (celular = '$celular')");
                $consulta->execute();

                $linha = $consulta->rowCount();

                foreach($consulta as $mostra):
                    $nome = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['nome']));
                    $email = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['email']));   
                    $senha = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['senha']));   
                endforeach;  

                if($linha):                   
                    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;                     
                    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;  
                endif;  

echo $nome;
echo $email;
echo $senha;


 $html = 'Olá ' . $nome . ', você pediu para recuperar sua senha. <br></br>


A sua senha é: ' .  $senha . '
<br></br>
Atenciosamente,
<br></br>
<b>Equipe VovóCooks,</b>
www.vovocooks.com.br';



$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'contato@vovocooks.com.br';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'sucessomundial2017';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('contato@vovocooks.com.br', 'VovoCooks App');
//$mail->addAddress('contato@vovocooks.com.br', 'VovóCooks App');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress($email);               // Name is optional

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Seu login e senha do VovoCooks App.';
$mail->Body    = $html;




if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'A mensagem não pode ser enviada.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;   
} else {
    echo 'Mensagem enviada';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=> 'Sua senha foi enviada para seu e-mail: ' + $to));
}


?>
```

Comment: Nesse seu código acima não há erros. Fiz teste no meu servidor e funciona corretamente. Talvez haja erro no formulário, caminho dos includes. Poste o formulário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o erro está na url veja que é `$_GET['email'];` e não `$_GET['o_email'];`

tem que ser `....?email=....` e não `....?o_email=....`

```
http://meusite.com.br/admin/apis/esqueci/esqueci_netinho.php?email=meumail@gmail.com
```

ou

```
http://meusite.com.br/admin/apis/esqueci/esqueci_netinho.php?celular=99......
```

Comment: Já havia tentando desta forma. Mas mesmo assim, me retorna a mensagem de erro: A mensagem nÃ£o pode ser enviada.Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Comment: Por exemplo, voltei como você falou a resposta e voltei o SQL:  $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nome, email, senha, celular FROM usuario_app WHERE email = '$email' OR (celular = '$celular')"); Que continua o mesmo erro....

Comment: Existe, já verifiquei na tabela e a forma escrita.

Comment: veja se chegou algo na sua CP

Comment: Funcionou numa outra tabela que tem a mesma finalidade. Vou ver o que pode ser nesta tabela. Pode ser que o e-mail tenha sido deletado, não sei. Mas mostra pra mim aqui.... no minimo curioso. Mas muito obrigado @Leo Caracciolo!

Comment: beleza, boa sorte

Comment: melhor apagar os comentários com seu email para não ficar exposto